# The better I do my puzzling the further I am from my goal

Tags: riddle

*My mother always told me

To try my best

And all the things I wish for

Will come to me



But I’m standing here

And I know

The better I do my puzzling

The further I am from my goal

Which is:



Downloading the latest movies (4)

and making a diamond, (8)

Grabbing a drink with my mates and colleagues (4)

and learning one of Newton’s laws in a small place. (8)*


What is my goal?

**Hint 1:**

> The last stanza is ment to give you two words. The first word is hinted in lines 1 and 3, and the second word is hinted in lines 2 and 4.

**Hint 2:**

> If the tag **meta-puzzle** was defined differently, I would use it for this puzzle (this is the piece that links the first 2 stanza to the solution of the third).

**Hint 3:**

> *"When you say 'yes' to others, be sure you are not saying 'no' to yourself"* - This is sooo not true for me!

**Hint 4:**

> A small place can be like one m^2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Peer pressure

First stanza

> Your mother advising you to do your best and not give in to peer pressure

Second stanza

> There is a badge on stack exchange called the [peer pressure](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge. You obtain it for deleting a post of your own that scores -3 or lower. If you do well with your puzzling, you will always get a positive score and never achieve this badge. So, you won't fulfil your ambition. This relates directly to Hint 2 and the idea that this should be a meta-puzzle.

Downloading the latest movies (4)

> [Peer-to-peer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer)

and making a diamond, (8)

> Diamonds are made under extreme pressure

Grabbing a drink with my mates and colleagues (4)

> Peer - a person of the same age, status, or ability as another specified person, e.g, your friends

and learning one of Newton’s laws in a small place. (8)

> Pressure is force over area, measured in, for example, Newtons per square metre.

Comment: Yes, so far, it is correct! One final thing is missing to correctly understand the role of the second stanza: use hint 2, and think of the found solution as something that connects on a meta level to the PSE, and to all Stack Exchange sites :)

Comment: @Annosz I've updated my answer now which I think is along the lines you are going for.

Answer (score 3):

I thought a lot and here is my answer (this is only a hypothesis).

> Downloading the latest movies
>   and finding a diamond,

means

> Download the latest movies is talking about the movie in which the actor Lou **Diamond** Phillips appears. The last movie in which he acted was "Adverse", in which Thomas Ian Nicholas, who is known to have acted in the movie "**Rules of Attraction"** also acted. And this is already connected to the continuation of the riddle .

the last line:

> and learning Newton’s laws in a small place.

And the explanation of the line before the last:

> Grabbing a drink with my mates and colleagues

mean to:

> The movie "Adverse" tells about  Dr. Cruz (Lou Diamond Phillips) who works as a parole officer and tries to prevent Ethan(The main character) from going back to his old habits that are drugs and duties that are somewhat like drinking alcohol, addictive and difficult to get out of.

If so, in my opinion, your goal is to be:

> **a parole officer** like Dr. Cruz ('cause you want to find a diamond )

Comment: Sadly, this answer is very far from my intended solution. Also, it doesn't explain the begining of the riddle or the title. But I will add hints to clarify what is my intention with the lines you used :)